# iOS 5 and Three20 SDK

Tags: ios, three20, ios5

i want to make compatible my apps with iOS 5. Everything goes well with iOS 4.3. After changing the main project and target compiler settings to Apple LLVM compiler 3.0, and set the Three20 project and target settings to LLVM GCC 4.2 i ran the application. Application runs well but at the photo gallery screen there is something which i do not want. There is the screenshot.

[iOS 5 http://www.portxl.com/ios/5.png](http://www.portxl.com/ios/5.png)

There is a rectangular block above the thumbnails. I ran the same application with the same codes in iOS 4.3 and there is no block. Screenshot is below.

[image: iOS 4.3]
<sub>(source: [portxl.com](http://www.portxl.com/ios/4-3.png))</sub>

Waiting your suggestions, thanks in advance.

There is a quick note : when i change Three20 project and target settings to Apple LLVM compiler 3.0, there is an error in a class of three20. When i scroll the tableview rectangular block comes with the tableview.

Comment: You should post this to the three20 issue tracker (and before that, check out the newest version) - https://github.com/facebook/three20

Comment: What have you tried to do to resolve this? Why did you update to LLVM3 when not all of your project works with it? What errors do you get when you compile with LLVM 3?

Comment: Thanks Tomen, i will post this issue to the three20 issue tracker after checking the newest version. Stephen Darlington, i made some changes in TTThumbsViewController and TTTableViewController classes there is nothing changed. I only updated the main project not three20. Now i made a change in the class that gives error when i updated the three20 LLVM 3M and three20 compiler is now LLVM 3M. Bu the rectangular block still is there.

Comment: hi guys, may be it will help to others, after i updated the Three20 to latest version problem was disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is in TTTableViewDelegate,

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section;
```

in iOS 5, this method must return 0 if you don't want the header section.

you can check the latest three20, it's been resolved.