# How can i create DashBoard?

Tags: iphone, xcode, cocoa-touch, ipad

I want to create a DashBoard in my Application like that https://i.stack.imgur.com/uDwlf.png.
The DashBoard has a UINavigationController and a UITabBarController, if i click on one of this buttons it will be push to the specific UIViewController and activate the current Tab Item and also it has UINavigationItem for back to the DashBoard. like that https://i.stack.imgur.com/2wCmq.png

Comment: possible duplicate of [iOS: Are there any open-source Launcher Views like the home screen?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7531246/ios-are-there-any-open-source-launcher-views-like-the-home-screen)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look at the [Three20 launcher](http://three20.info/showcase/launcher). It's pretty much exactly what you're looking for. Its documentation says this

> Three20 provides an open-source implementation of the standard app
>   launcher control found on all iOS devices. The Launcher supports
>   reordering and deletion of items, custom column and row counts, and
>   multiple pages of content. It also works on the iPad.

Comment: i can't add Three20 to my project i use iOS 5? how can i do?

Comment: It seems to be possible http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7836296/ios-5-and-three20-sdk

Comment: can you check these warnings http://i.stack.imgur.com/LGxGp.png
http://i.stack.imgur.com/8tCip.png and tell me what's the problem

Comment: I think its complaining (amongst other things) that TT isn't using ARC, do you actually get errors or just warnings?

Comment: In that case you should be able to use the library.

Comment: there is no problem to the validation of apple if I let these warnings?

Comment: Do you have some tutorials for this library?

Comment: any tutorials ..for this dashboard concept,... would be helpful